# UTF-8 vs Latin1 mysql, indexes not used on utf-8

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have tried creating my mysql tables with both UTF-8 and Latin1 Char sets. When I use Latin1 my indexes are used, when I use UTF-8 indexes are not used when selecting/limiting records. Is there something I am missing with the Char sets that causes this to happen?

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indexes can be used only when the expression's collation matches that on the indexed column.

If the expression's `COERCIBILITY` is lower than that of the column (that is `2`), the column's collation is casted to that of the expression, and the index is not used.

Normally, literals have `COERCIBILITY` of `4` and user variables that of `3`, so this should be not a problem.

However, if you mix different collations in a `JOIN` or `UNION`, the cast order is not guaranteed.

In this case you should provide explicit collation to the column your are casting (most probably, you want to cast `latin1` to `UTF8`), and this should be the collation of the column you are casting to:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    utf_table
JOIN    latin_table
ON      utf_column = latin_column COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI
```

Comment: Thanks @Quassnoi could you supply some official document about this? I want to know more.

Comment: @zhuguowei: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_coercibility

Comment: Thanks! but I want to know more of this: `Indexes can be used only when the expression's collation matches that on the indexed column.` Because recently I had met this problem `where a.user_id(UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI) = b.user_id(utf8_bin)` and both table  `user_id` is indexed and actually it is very slow, explicitly the index is not work.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this now, the tables i was joining were not of the same char set

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Once I changed these the indexes worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The indexes themselves are stored with the same encoding as the columns they are indexing. Comparing a UTF-8 character to a latin1 character cannot make use of the index, because it would need to convert both to the same encoding, since the index optimizations are performed on a byte level (and `ß` in latin1 has a different byte sequence than in UTF-8).