# PDO - a specific query is drastically slow compared to manual execution

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm experiencing a drasticily slow query execution with a specific query (written below).

The weird thing is, when running the query manually (using phpMyAdmin), **it only takes a second to complete**, while running it from PHP with PDO, it takes **almost 10 minutes!**

**Other queries execute normally (equal durations between PDO & phpMyAdmin).**

Technical details:

- I'm using Google's AppEngine & Cloud SQL.
- Running PHP5.5
- The app engine instance executing the php code isn't busy.
- The query results with about 10,000 rows

The query I'm running:

```
SELECT s.saleID,s.year,s.kilometrage,s.hand,s.price,s.pictures,u.platform,s.date,
   (SELECT AVG(price) FROM sales s2 WHERE s2.carID = s.carID AND s2.year = s.year HAVING COUNT(s2.saleID)>5) AS avgPrice
   FROM sales s JOIN users u ON u.ID = s.sellerID LEFT JOIN sold so ON s.saleID = so.saleID WHERE so.saleID IS NULL
```

Any hints on this issue? It can't be related to indexes since the query runs perfectly well under phpMyAdmin.

#### Edit

In case someone is also having this - seems like PMA adds an implicit LIMIT on the query for paging, which makes everything runs faster in some cases.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with one query. My only guess is that it's related to the joins I do. If I remove one of them it works fine even via Pdo

Comment: But why would the JOINs slow the query down only when executed via PDO? I mean, if the query is slow, it should be slow on both PDO and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: That's the point I haven't understood yet. I asked the same in a unanswered question here on so

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13345776/3585500) might help. There's a PDO EXPLAIN command to see what the planner is doing. There's also index hinting to tell it how to run. See also [the answer below that about type casting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338800/3585500).

Answer (score 1):

Try to write query without subquery in field list. Something like this:

```
SELECT s.saleID, s.year, s.kilometrage, s.hand, 
   s.price, s.pictures, u.platform, s.date,
   t.avgPrice
FROM sales s 
JOIN users u ON u.ID = s.sellerID 
LEFT JOIN sold so ON s.saleID = so.saleID 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(s2.price) as avgPrice, s2.carID, s2.year
    FROM sales s2 
    GROUP BY s2.carID, s2.year
    HAVING COUNT(s2.saleID) > 5
) t ON t.carID = s.carID AND t.year = s2.year
WHERE so.saleID IS NULL
```