# Mysql Query Plan different in PHP compared to Query Plan generated via Navicat

Tags: php, mysql, query-planner

I am quite confused at the time of posting this.
I do not understand why the query plan for the query is different when I fire the EXPLAIN in php vs firing the EXPLAIN for the EXACT same query in navicat.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(`SaleID`) AS 'LatestSaleID',
    MAX(`SaleDate`) AS 'MyLastVisit',
    COUNT(SaleID) AS 'MyNumVisits'                          
FROM sales_table
WHERE sales_table.CustomerID = '5207'
```

Explain output in Navicat:

- id - 1
- select_type - SIMPLE
- table - sales_table
- partitions - NULL
- type - ref
- possible_keys - CustomerID
- key - CustomerID
- key_len - 22
- ref - const
- rows - 1
- filtered - 100
- Extra - NULL

Explain output when fired from PHP:

- id - 1
- select_type - SIMPLE
- table - sales_table
- partitions - NULL
- **type - ALL**
- possible_keys - CustomerID
- **key - NULL**
- **key_len - NULL**
- **ref - NULL**
- **rows - 1772719**
- **filtered - 10.00**
- **Extra - Using where**

As you can see, the explain output is vastly different.  Due to this difference, the query takes 4 times longer to execute from my PHP page.

I tried using a forced index.  However, that did not work either.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(`SaleID`) AS 'LatestSaleID',
    MAX(`SaleDate`) AS 'MyLastVisit',
    COUNT(SaleID) AS 'MyNumVisits'                          
FROM sales_table USE INDEX(CustomerID)
WHERE sales_table.CustomerID = '5207'
```

I found a related post - [PHP takes 90x longer to run query than MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336457/php-takes-90x-longer-to-run-query-than-mysql-client).  However, I have not been able to find any information regarding query plan differences.

This is a legacy app which is still using mysql_query.

- PHP Version - 5.6.34-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
- Mysqlnd version - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503

Comment: To ask the obvious, are both these queries running on the same database with the same exact underlying table data?

Comment: Yep.  Same database, same data.